# is onChange triggered if the value is changed by parent?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

```
const [value, set_value] = useState({a: 1});

<Child
  value={value}
  onChange={callback}
</Child>

set_value({a: 2})
```

When `set_value({a: 2})` is run, will that trigger the `callback` inside of the `onChange` to run?

Comment: No. It will trigger a re-render.

Comment: Could you clarify. Your statement is confusing.

Comment: Why _would_ it? Certainly not directly, but what does `Child` do with `onChange`? Where does `callback` come from? Why not add `console.log("I got called")` into it, run the code and find out?

Comment: jonrsharpe is right, in fact, we can't be absolutely sure since you didn't provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most exact answer to the question is:
"That is up to the `<Child>` component."

From Reacts point of view `value` and `onChange` are just two properties of `<Child>`, so:
No, changing one property (`value`) doesn't necessarily cause any callbacks (`onChange`) to be called.

**But** it is common in React to have so called ["controlled-components"](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), where the state (i.e. the value)
is kept inside the parent, and the child doesn't have any own state, but will receive the value from the parent,
and only informs the parent about changes.

In your example the parent component keeps the state:

```
const [value, set_value] = useState({a: 1});
```

And the child might only receive the value and call the callback if changes are necessary (but doesn't keep any own state), e.g.:

```
const Child = function( props ){
  return <button onClick={ function(){
    props.onChange( props.value.a + 1 );
  }}>
    { props.value.a }
  </button>
};
```